# How to get accurate deltaTime in Java

Tags: java, timedelta

I just got done learning Java not long ago and right now I am working on my first java game. The problem is when I try to get delta time in my main loop delta time often is 0. How can I fix this? code for my main loop:

```
double deltaTime=0;
    while(!windowIsClosed){         //main loop
        double beginTime=System.nanoTime()/1e9;  //divide by 1e9 because I want time variables to be in seconds

        animations(deltaTime);
        repaint();


        double endTime=System.nanoTime()/1e9;
        deltaTime=endTime-beginTime;
```

Comment: Using Java to create a game is like using ice cream to build a house. The material is insufficient for the task at hand.

Comment: Minecraft after seeing above comment be like: (o-o) (>->)

Comment: Your delta time is often 0 because your logic and render actions are likely nearly empty, so the time it takes to run them are negligible.

If you calculated your FPS you likely will find it in the thousands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overwrite your beginTime at the start of the while loop, so what you calculate right now is how long the animation takes to finish.
If you want to calculate the delta from starting the while-loop you should place the assignment of beginTime above the while.

Also if you are using Java 8 you could use the new Date/Time-API and make use of classes like Instant to store the start and end times and Duration to calculate the duration between two of those points in time:

```
Duration deltaTime = Duration.ZERO;
Instant beginTime = Instant.now();
while(!windowIsClosed){

    animations(deltaTime);
    repaint();

    deltaTime = Duration.between(beginTime, Instant.now());
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Delta Time is supposed to be the amount of time that it takes to run the loop. The actual answer to the OP's question, is that their loop was so fast that their delta time was 0.

Your solution would continue to generate larger and larger DeltaTimes as the application runs, which is not what a delta time is supposed to be.

Comment: If you read my post carefully, that's exactly what I said ("so what you calculate right now is how long the animation takes to finish"). If he really needs the time per cicle, he just has to move the assignment of beginTime back into the loop.
And we honestly don't know what OP wants with this. What if he wants to calculate how long the window was open, e.g. how long it took the player to solve a certain riddle?

Comment: I suppose you are technically correct. But considering the OP said that they had just learned Java and were looking to make a game loop. Best Standards and Practices are that delta time is the time between loops in said game loop. Not the start time - current time.

The OP asked, why is my delta time zero. Your answer that they overwrote begin time every loop is half the answer, the full answer is that, their delta time really was zero and that is a valid solution. Not to further confuse them by directing them to a completely non standard use of delta time in a game loop. Respectfully IMO.